# Is it possible to Identify and differentiate a Sidewalk & Crosswalk from a Road/Street (drivable Surface)?

Tags: android

I've been looking at various Map APIs and can not find any information on how to differentiate Sidewalks & Crosswalks from a drivable surface (road).

It seems like Maps simply know if a Road has foot access but it doesn't differentiate the elements (Road from Sidewalk/Crosswalk).

Am I out of luck?